# Sort C# map with value and key

Tags: c#, linq

Looking for a built-in way (preferable one-liner) to reproduce this Python line in C#.

```
sorted_weights = sorted(weights, key=lambda weight: (weight[1], weight[0]))
```

It sorts the map/dictionary using first the value and if there are duplicated values, it should sort using keys. (please note: both, keys and values, are integers)

I'd like to avoid writing an own function/loop (which I am capable of ;)) to achieve sorting if not needed. I'm pretty sure there is a functional programming approach in C# for this as well, isn't there?

Comment: What's the collection type you're working with? In .Net, a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is unsorted - the access to the values is done via keys, not via indexes (and though you can iterate it because it does implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`  [the order is undefined:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined."...)

Comment: Yes, I am working with a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Thanks, it was an important hint that a dictionary is unsorted in .Net. (I am going to use Artfunkel's and Gur Galler's suggestion and access the first element (which I need) with `sorted_weights.FirstOrDefault().Key`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

A one-liner:

Assuming your Weights have properties Value and Key:

```
var sortedWeights = weights.SortedBy(weight => weight.Value).ThenBy(weight => weight.Key);
```

### Reusable method

Apparently your input is a sequence of similar items, and you want to sort first by one property, followed by a sort in another property.

My advice would be to create an extension method. After that you can use it as a one-liner LINQ like method. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

To make it reusable, your `<int, int>` version calls a generic method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TSort1, TSort2>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSort1> sortProperty1,
    Func<TSource, TSort2> sortProperty2)
{
    return source.OrderBy(item => sortProperty1(item)
                 .ThenBy(item => sortProperty2(item);
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Weight> weights = ...

// sort by Weight.Value then by Id:
var result = weights.OrderBy(weight => weight.Value, weight => weight.Id);
```

Or A dictionary, order by Weight.X then by dictionary key:

```
Dictionary<int, Weights> dict = ...
var result = dict.OrderBy(dictItem => dictItem.Value.X,
                          dictItem => dictItem.Key);
```

If you don't want to mention the second sort property, consider adding an extra extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> OrderByThenByKey<TKey, TValue, TProperty>(
    // TODO: invent a proper method name
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source,
    Func<TValue, TProperty> propertySelector)
{
    // call the other OrderBy
    return source.OrderBy(propertySelector, keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key);
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<int, Weight> dict = ...
var result = dict.OrderByThenByKey(weight => weight.X);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `weights` is a dictionary, you can try:

```
//using System.Linq;
var sortedWeights = weights.OrderBy(weight => weight.Value).ThenBy(weight => weight.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what that Python code produces, but if it's a flat list of weight objects then this C# line does the same thing:

```
using System.Linq;

var sorted_weights = weights.OrderBy(weight => (weight[1], weight[0]));
```

Just be aware that output object is the equivalent of a Python generator. It will only be evaluated when you enumerate over it.

Comment: Might as well include version for old net framework - *weights.OrderBy(weight => weight[1]).ThenBy(weight => weight[0])*

Comment: Is that the same thing? The Python code looks like it sorts by both variables at the same time, not one after the other. I'm not sure how it produces a sort order, actually.

Comment: Yes, if there is duplicate, it will sort by key. The python sort is not relevant, in the example above, you just construct iterator, the evaluation will be performed on combined lambda, when you *foreach* it or convert to collection in memory. This is very frequent scenario which is supported in databases. In SQL for  example - *ORDER BY weight.value ASC, weight.key ASC*

Comment: It's actually a dictionary but `weights.OrderBy(element => (element.Value, element.Key))` works for me.